# Sending pcap file via packetgen dpdk

Tags: dpdk

Sending a pcap file on port 0. I get the following error. Any fix would be appreciated!

[image: Sending pcap file via packetgen dpdk]

The command used is:

sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X01 -n 1  --file-prefix=pg -w 4:00.1 -- -m 1.0 -T -P -s 0:~/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 obvious reasons for the failure.

1. Number of CPU cores for pktgen to work is `1 + number of ports in use`
2. you have extra argument in comamnd executed in pktgen.

Checking the link, it show the command used is `sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X01 -n 1 --file-prefix=pg -w 4:00.1 -- -m 1.0 -T -P -s 0:[~/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap]`. You should not sue `[]` instead use `0:actual path to pcap`.

Note: @SaifUllah during the live debug both core and pcap were show cased for you.

Comment: Yes am using two CPUs. the master CPU runs by default. Also during the live debug traffic was sent not an exsisting pcap file. specifically via packetgen dpdk.  The command am using is :

Comment: sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X01 -n 1 --file-prefix=pg -w 4:00.1 -- -m 1.0 -T -P -s 0:~/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Comment: option `-c 0X01 ` in dpdk stands for use core 0 in entire application. There are no 2 lcores. Please correct.

Comment: Thankyou Vipin. Changed to this changing the -c and -n, still same error

Comment: sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X02 -n 2 --file-prefix=pg -w 4:00.1 -- -m 1.0 -T -P -s 0:~/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Comment: this is wrong, because `-c 0x02` stand for bit 2 that core 1. So there is only 1 core,.

Comment: Thanks Vipin, I forgot that concept. But still the same error. It has to be something else.

Comment: sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X03 -n 2 --file-prefix=pg -w 4:00.1 -- -m 1.0 -T -P -s 0:~/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Comment: ok core mask looks correct,  but whitelist `-w` does not look right

Comment: waiting for your result on using actual path `/home/user/Download/test.pcap` instead of `~/Download/test.pcap`

Comment: Ok I think it will work now. But for some unknown reason my igb_uio module starts giving error suddenly and it wont load up. So I would have to fix the igb_uio module for now

Comment: sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X02 -n 2 --file-prefix=pg -w 00:08.0 -- -m 0.1 -T -P -s 0:/home/saif/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Comment: the command solves the problem. accept and upvote. If you have logs for your IGB_UIO open a new ticket.