# ====== Pktgen got a Segment Fault

Tags: dpdk

Got a **( ====== Pktgen got a Segment Fault )** error while sending a pcap file via pktgen dpdk.

I used the following command to send a pcap file on port 0:

sudo ./app/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/pktgen -c 0X02 -n 2 --file-prefix=pg -w 00:08.0 -- -m 0.1 -T -P -s 0:/home/saif/Downloads/bigFlows.pcap

Also tried sending different pcap files. Still same error.

Image :

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending pcap file via packetgen dpdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk/64548938#64548938 and use right aarguments

Comment: if you have rebuild `igb_uio`, unbind and bind the virtio-pci with the new igb_uio. Use the command line option shared in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk/64548938#64548938

Comment: Yes I have binded with the new igb_uio

Comment: The above error I don't think has to do something with the arguments

Comment: The above answer does load up pcap file on port 0. so that solves, but the pktgen got a segment fault is something else.

Comment: in your question you have shared ` -c 0X02` fix this first. Then run under gdb to identify the seg fault.

Comment: Solved. I did the same mistake using mask 0x02. changing it to 0x03 solves the problem.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate since the solution in [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk/64548938#64548938) solves the same,

Comment: Once again I have to callout https://stackoverflow.com/users/4806927/il-raffa, without understanding it is DPDK application usage issue has flagged and rejected the edit changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in usage of DPDK pktgen application parameters. Changing the core mask from `0x2` to `0x3` solves the problem (as confirmed in comments). Also the solution shared is same as [simialr issued raised by @SaifUllah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk/64548938#64548938)

Comment: @saifullah from the comment it shows the issue is resolved. please accept and upvote