# Pktgen error - Invalid PCAP filename, must include port number as P:filename

Tags: pcap, dpdk

I'm trying to run Pktgen and record packet data to a pcap file. When I'm running this command:

```
./usr/local/bin/pktgen --no-telemetry -l 4,6,8 -n 4 -a 0000:03:02.0 -m 1024 -- -T -P -m [6:8].0 -s 0:pcap/captured_packets.pcap
```

It returns the following error message:

```
_pcap_open: failed to read the file header
!ERROR!: Invalid PCAP filename (0:pcap/captured_packets.pcap) must include port number as P:filename
```

What is wrong with the command? It seems to like the syntax of the command should be correct, so maybe it has something to do with the ports? If I run it without `-s 0:pcap/captured_packets.pcap` Pktgen works as it should.

I have also checked out a previous thread on this ([Sending pcap file via packetgen dpdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548432/sending-pcap-file-via-packetgen-dpdk)), but it didn't give any further input into how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `pktgen`, the `-s <port>:<pcap file>` is only used for playback.  It has a couple of drawbacks, including that it doesn't honor pcap timestamps and will just play at whatever rate is configured by the user.  The other drawback is that I believe pktgen does not send jumbo packets in their entirety, but will limit any sent packet to the size of the payload section in a single `rte_membuf`.

If you're interested in using DPDK to record pcaps, you may look into [`dpdk-pdump`](https://doc.dpdk.org/dts/test_plans/packet_capture_test_plan.html) and [`dumpcap`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/tools/dumpcap.html).

I've also had good performance in the past when building my own packet recorder, especially since I know I can program it to receive and record any jumbo packets and run across any number of queues and threads.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification. Would it be possible to use dpdk-pdump to measure receiving packets in Pktgen as well? I see that is a application which comes with dpdk, so do you simply turn it on and ask it to check the incoming packets on then Pktgen port, when your are sending packets between Pktgen and TestPMD?

Comment: Actually, it looks like both of the ones I recommended will only work with test-pmd "out of the box."  [dumpcap doc.](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/tools/dumpcap.html) mentions this and also mentions how you can attempt to modify other programs to initialize a [packet capture framework](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-16.07/prog_guide/pdump_lib.html).  So that gives you two starter options:  1) grab packets from test-pmd or 2) modify pktgen to initialize packet capture.  If you are using the e1000 as mentioned in another question at 1Gbps max, you should be ok doing either on most modern PCs.